# Error in content(urlb, as = "text") : is.response(x) is not TRUE in R

Tags: r, rvest, httr

I am trying to access the text from multiple links on a web page in order to build a training corpus for some machine learning algorithms.

I can create the list of links, but I'm unable to extract the text from each website.  I'm using a function called `scrape_gold_articles` which passes each url to the function and returns the text from the article.

```
scrape_gold_article <- function(urlb) {

    html_document <- read_html(httr::content(urlb, as = "text"))
    current_articles <- html_document %>% 
    html_nodes(html_document, 'p') %>%
    html_text(trim = T)
    paste0(collapse = "\n")

    article <- data.frame(body = paste0(current_articles))

    return(article)
}

all_articles <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:length(forecast_Articles)) {

     article <- scrape_gold_article(forecast_Articles[i])

     all_articles <- rbind(all_articles, current_articles)
}
```

When the code reaches the `all_articles <- rbind(all_articles, current_articles)` line, it generates the following error message.

> "Error in content(urlb, as = "text") : is.response(x) is not TRUE"

Does anyone have a fix for this, or an alternative way of looping through a series of links, extracting the text from the url and appending it to a file of existing text?  Any help would be appreciated.

regards

Comment: Could you show sample usage of this function? `content` expects an object from `GET`

Comment: If I remove content, I get the following error.  "Error: Please supply css or xpath," not both.

Comment: so what king of object is `urlb`, can you give an example of it?

Comment: urlb is receiving the url for each subsequent webpage.  I've change it to "forecast_Articles" which is in the function call (typeof reveals it to be a character string) but now I am back to the original error.